# Triggers: Using Condition statements

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers, sql-insert

Please have a look at the below query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Ongoing_Portfolio_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Ongoing_Portfolio` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Portfolio
    SET Invest_Amount = New.Investment_Value,
    Cash_Value = New.Cash_Value,
    Date_Of_Last_Update = New.Updated_Date
    WHERE idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;

    INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (currentDate, Ongoing_Gross_Fee,Ongoing_Vat, Updated_Date, idPortfolio)
    SELECT current_timestamp,
    (New.Investment_Value+New.Cash_Value)*(p.Ongoing_Gross_Fee/100),
    (((New.Investment_Value+New.Cash_Value)*(p.Ongoing_Gross_Fee/100))*(p.Ongoing_eee_Fee/100))*0.2,
    New.Updated_Date,
    New.idPortfolio
    FROM Portfolio p
    WHERE p.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;
END;
```

However in here, the `Ongoing_Vat` is only applicable if `p.Vat = true`, otherwise it is `NULL`. How can I add this conditional statement so the `Ongoing_Vat` will be calculated properly?

Comment: case when p.vat = true then ongoing_vat else null end?

Comment: @paqogomez: How can I add that conditional statement?

Comment: @Twelfth: I don't understand. Can you please add that part to my code? I am somewhat new to SQL stuff.

Comment: quite literally...replace "ongoing_vat" with "case when p.vat = true then ongoing_vat else null end".  Think of a case statement as an 'if'...if this condition is true, then do this.  In your case...if p.vat is true, then use ongoing_vat...otherwise (else) use null.

Comment: you mean ` case when p.vat = true then ongoing_vat= (((New.Investment_Value+New.Cash_Value)*(p.Ongoing_Gross_Fee/100))*(p.Ongoing_eee_Fee/100))*0.2 else null end` ?

Comment: @Twelfth, wouldnt you want to put that code in the select portion of the insert statement?  The only place i see "ongoing vat" is in the column names of the insert.

Comment: @paqogomez: True, I also have the same issue. Mind editing it please?

Comment: ah yes, ty @paqogomez...didn't quite have the attention to give that this question needed.  stupid work.  ha

Comment: @Twelfth, all that means is that you are a better employee than I am. :D

Comment: I tried to get my ratio of work to stack overflow hours as : select sum(workhours) / sum(workhours) - sum(hoursonstack)   ...stupid thing gave me a divide by 0 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @Twelfth's answer in comments, formatted in code it would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (currentDate, Ongoing_Gross_Fee,Ongoing_Vat, Updated_Date, idPortfolio)
SELECT 
  current_timestamp as currentDate,
  (New.Investment_Value+New.Cash_Value)*(p.Ongoing_Gross_Fee/100) as Ongoing_Gross_Fee,
  case when p.vat = true then (((New.Investment_Value+New.Cash_Value)*(p.Ongoing_Gross_Fee/100))*(p.Ongoing_eee_Fee/100))*0.2 
    else null end as Ongoing_Vat,
  New.Updated_Date as Updated_Date,
  New.idPortfolio as idPortfolio
FROM 
  Portfolio p
WHERE 
  p.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;
```

Comment: Mind answering here please? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294825/variable-is-getting-null-after-calculations-in-mysql-trigger