# Variable is getting NULL after calculations in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, jdbc, triggers, null

I have a table called `Initial_Fees`. There is a column in this table called `Initial_Consult_Fee` where it cannot be more than 30,000 per year. Below is my table.

```
    CREATE TABLE `initial_fees` (
 `idInitial_Fees` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `idPortfolio` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Current_Time_Stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Initial_Gross_Fee` double NOT NULL,
 `Initial_Consult_Fee` double NOT NULL,
 `Updated_Date` date NOT NULL,
 `idTransactions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idInitial_Fees`)
)
```

So, I created a trigger, that will do the check, whether the `Initial_Consult_Fee` is above 30,000 or not. Apart from that, it will round all the values.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Initial_Fees_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `Initial_Fees` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    DECLARE `initial` DOUBLE;
    DECLARE `ongoing` DOUBLE;
    DECLARE `total` DOUBLE;
    DECLARE `valueToBeEntered` DOUBLE;

    SET `initial`:=(SELECT SUM(`Initial_Consult_Fee` ) FROM `Initial_Fees` WHERE `Updated_Date` BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(New.Updated_Date),1) AND MAKEDATE(YEAR(New.Updated_Date),365));
    SET `ongoing`:=(SELECT SUM(`Ongoing_Consult_Fee` ) FROM `Ongoing_Fees` WHERE `Updated_Date` BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(New.Updated_Date),1) AND MAKEDATE(YEAR(New.Updated_Date),365));
    SET `total` := `initial`+`ongoing`;

    IF((New.Initial_Consult_Fee+`total`) > 30000) THEN
        SET `valueToBeEntered`:= 30000 - `total`;
    END IF;

    IF((New.Initial_Consult_Fee+`total`) < 30000) THEN
        SET `valueToBeEntered`:= New.Initial_Consult_Fee;
    END IF;


SET New.Initial_Gross_Fee = ROUND(New.Initial_Gross_Fee,2),
New.Initial_Consult_Fee = ROUND(`valueToBeEntered`,2);
END;
```

However, when I enter data, and if the `New.Initial_Vision_Fee+total` I get the below error

```
Column 'Initial_Consult_Fee' cannot be null
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

A few comments.

First, you are looking at the total consulting fees across all portfolios.  That seems unusual.  It does conform to your description, but I would expect the total to be based on some factor, such as the portfolio.

Second, your problem is occurring when there are no matches in the `ingoing` or `outgoing` tables.  Then the values of your variables are `NULL`.

You can readily fix this by doing something like:

```
 SET `total` := coalesce(`initial`, 0) + coalesce(`ongoing`, 0);
```

Comment: @Sniper . . . What you say seems highly unlikely.  The fix in the answer should guarantee that `total` is never `NULL`, and, by my reading of the code, this is the only way that the value could be set to `NULL` unless `New.Initial_Consult_Fee` is NULL.  In that case, set the new value to `coalesce(New.Initial_Consult_Fee, 0)`.